# Bash script: rename all files below a directory?

Tags: bash, shell-script

Here's what I'd like to do in pseudocode:

```
for subdir in [all first-level subdirectories of the current directory]:
    for file in [all files in subdir]:
        rename file to "myprefix_" + current_filename_padded_with_zeroes
```

What I mean by `current_filename_padded_with_zeroes` is e.g. if the current filename is `01.png` change to `0001.png`, or `100.png` change it to `0100.png`.

Can anyone help me translate the above into a bash script?

Something like... I'm not sure how to do the renaming part:

```
#!/bin/bash
for DIR in $(ls) 
do
    for FILENAME in $(ls $DIR)
        do
        mv "$FILENAME" "myprefix_{%FILENAME}"   
        done
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following to rename all files in the current directory:

```
for file in * ; do
    mv "$file" "myprefix_$( printf "%04d" $file )"
done
```

The `printf` program is similar to the function of the same name in quite a few programming languages.

---

You need to use `basename` and `dirname` to make it work from a different directory.

Answer (score 1):

Use `printf` to pad zeros until it matches the length you want. `%04d` means filling zeros to a length of 4 digits (if your number is >= 4 digits, it won't change anything). `${a%.png}` matches the part of `$a` before `.png`. Some `basename` and `dirname` is required to extract the actual filename from the path and reconcatenate it.

You can replace the loop using `find . -dept 2`.

```
find . -depth 2 -exec bash -c 'FILENAME=`basename {}`; mv {} `printf \`dirname {}\`/%04d.png ${FILENAME%.png}`'  \;
```